# digital signature without using a Java applet?

Tags: digital-signature

I am trying to do a search if we can do an electronic signature without using a java applet to retrieve the certificate from the hard drive client station that is to say there is another method to retrieve the certificate? is that one can store the certificate remotely in a secure manner (not on a USB key or smart card)
I saw some example that used the javascript but it is not advisable listed security this article shows that http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/.
 can i store the certificate and private key addition to hard drive computer or on a USB key or smart card with a secure manner??
I hope so that there is someone who has ideas on this subject
thank you in advance

Comment: For windows you can create keystore with using java keytool. In linux openssl is usable.

Comment: yes I know but my issue it was to sign a document it is necessary to use an applet that accesses the personal certificate.  can we  avoid the use of a java applet to retrieve a certificate stored in the hard disk of a client?

Answer (score 0):

Java applets are not supported by modern browsers. Many people or vendors run service and then call it from Browser using http://localhost:portnumber but that is not clean method. On some devices, port may be blocked or virus scanners block the communication. You may use Browser Extensions (which runs host application in Browser sandbox and is more secure) from modern browsers to achieve the task.  One such Browser Extension JavaScript API are listed in this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885)